# GlobalSign R1 not in default trust on CentOS. Why?

Tags: centos, ssl-certificate, trusted-root-certificates, pki

It seems GlobalSign's R1 root certificate is not in the default trust CA in CentOS 7.3.

I check the list of Trusted CA's like this:

```
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '
    /BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Here is the list of GlobalSign's root certificates:
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1426602-globalsign-root-certificates

Is there a reason why the R1 is not in that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R1 root wasn't actually named "R1" at the time it was generated. Its actual subject name is:

```
CN=GlobalSign Root CA, OU=Root CA, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
```

It is common for old roots to lack the numbering, because at that time nobody thought they would need *more than one root* ~20 years in the future.